# Is it safe using Ehcache in Java webapp

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, ehcache

My web application needs to download the data from external server for some requests. The data from the external server does not change much, so I am thinking to use Ehcache to cache the data for certain period of time to improve the performance.

I have read that creating thread without using the Servlet thread pool is not recommended in the Java webapp environment. The cache has timeout, I guess there must be a thread whose job is to clear the expired data periodically. If that's the case, my question would be is it safe to use Ehcache in a web application (because I doubt Ehcache will use thread from Servlet thread pool).

p.s. I know Spring framework has integration with Ehcache, but I am not using any framework for this case.

Comment: Yes. It is. Otherwise it would not be a very helpful caching library.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use ehcache in your web app.  We use it extensively.

Comment: Thx for the confirmation.